# How to make parent job to wait for child job's status when calling it using curl command in jenkins?

Tags: curl, jenkins, status

I am calling a child job in a while loop of parent job using

```
curl -u username:password JENKINS_URL/job/job_name/build?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

or

```
curl -u username:password JENKINS_URL/job/job_name/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME
```

If I am running a loop twice, the child job will be called two times but I want parent job to wait till child job is running and gives final success/failure status every time. MultiJob Plugin doesn't allow me to run through loop. My parent job should also fail on failing of child. Please suggest me the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for the above job:-
1. Pipeline Plugin
2. Write a simple code to poll for the child job status after every few seconds. e.g.

```
JOB_STATUS_URL_XML="http://jenkins_url/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=1"

result="true"

# Calling a job

curl -u "username:password" "http://jenkins_url/job/job_name/buildWithParameters?token=token_name&parm_1=$value"

# Poll every thirty seconds until the job is finished

while [ "$result" == "true" ]

do      

    sleep 30

        # Grep will return build status (true if build is still running)

        result=$(curl --user username:password --silent $JOB_STATUS_URL_XML | grep -oP '(?).*(?=>/building)')

done

# Grep the result status

JOB_STATUS=$(curl --user username:password --silent $JOB_STATUS_URL_XML | grep -oP '(?).*(?=>/result)')

echo $JOB_STATUS
```